# PHP Curl wont send POST request

Tags: php, ajax, forms, curl

i have a html page that submits 2 forms(formone & formtwo) via ajax on one button click.
formone is submitted to formone.php and if it was succesfully sent formtwo is submitted to formtwo.php.
Everything works fine. Except i need to send data via POST to another php script (on another server, but for now i'm testing it on the same server).
I tried it with the following code but it wont work (i don't get any errors though).

**Curl code i used!**

```
function transferData()
{
//Set up some vars
$url = 'test.php';
$user = 'sampletext';
$pw = 'sampletext';

$fields = array(
            'user'=>urlencode($user),
            'pw'=>urlencode($pw)
        );

// Init. string
$fields_string = '';
// URL-ify stuff
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
}
```

**This is the code for my ajax form submission:**

```
function submitforms()
{
    FormSubmissionOne();
    function FormSubmissionOne() 
    {
        //Form 1
        var $form = $('#formone');
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (msg) 
            {
                FormSubmissionTwo();
            },
            error: function(msg) 
            {
             alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    function FormSubmissionTwo() 
    {
        //Form 2
        var $form2 = $('#formtwo'); 
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form2.attr('action'),
            data: $form2.serialize(),
            success: function (msg) 
            {
                alert(msg);
                //redirection link 
                window.location = "test.php";
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

**This is test.php (receiving script from curl function)**

```
  $one = $_POST['user'];
  $two = $_POST['pw'];

  echo "results:";
  echo $one;
  echo "\r\n";
  echo $two;
  echo "\r\n";
```

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path for the php file that you're sending it to? i.e. - `http://www.example.com/test.php`

Comment: i did try that, but i get the same resutl (no result!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues, firstly, `CURLOPT_POST` is for a `boolean` not a count.

So change this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); // or true
```

Secondly, you need to tell CURL that you want the returned data. You do that using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

So your `curl` related code should look like this:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result); // just see if result
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```